# Ffmpeg Scrolling end credits with transparend background from png

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

Trying to create an end credit video from the following large pixel png file (with transparent background). Creating the scrolling video works but the background is not transparent. What is wrong with my command?

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080 -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "credits.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=60[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" -pix_fmt yuva420p -vcodec prores_ks credits.mov
```

The picture I am using
[image]

Comment: `color=s=1920x1080` is not transparent. Also what's the actual `pix_fmt` is it using? `prores_ks` does not support `yuva420p`. Its only supported transparent format is `yuva444p10le` (per `ffmpeg -h encoder=prores_ks`). Anyway, consider outputting only the first frame to PNG to make sure output frames are indeed transparent.

Comment: Thanks you are right, I updated the string to `color=green@0.0:s=1920x1080,format=rgba` and used the `yuva444p10le` format. My new string looks like this, but the video still comes up with a full green background at full opacity. Any further pointers? 
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=green@0.0:s=1920x1080,format=rgba -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "credits.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=60[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -vcodec prores_ks credits.mov`

Comment: I think you need `colorkey` there: `color=green:s=1920x1080,colorkey=green`. I didn't have good luck producing transparent frame just with a `color` filter in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Kesh using colorkey worked with the following command

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=red:s=1920x1080,colorkey=red,format=rgba -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "credits.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=60[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -vcodec prores_ks credits.mov
```